# Insert duplicate rows from temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confused how to insert values from the declared table to the selected table. I used except to prevent insert of the first duplicate, but I want to make the second row of the duplicate be inserted.

[image: Storage of the table]
How can I put the second value to the table above?
[image: Temporary table]
My point to achieve here is to insert the second value in the primary table to manipulate is time_mode value.

This is my query

```
INSERT INTO temp_time(SwipeID,tdate,ttime,time_mode,raw_data,[Shift],eid,machineip)
    SELECT a.SwipeID,a.tdate,a.ttime,a.time_mode,a.raw_data,1, eid FROM @temp_time
    EXCEPT
    SELECT SwipeID,tdate,ttime,time_mode,raw_data,Shift,eid,machineip from temp_time
```

From the query above, only one value is inserted. My clients changed their minds that they want the duplicated values to be reflected. Changing the values on time_mode can be changed by the system i made. If I use the query again using insert without the except value, there would be 3 rows for the primary table which causes a problem because what I wanted to reflect is only the 2 rows.

Comment: Why would you want to insert a duplicate value? Usually that's the kind of thing you want to get rid of.

Comment: If you want to create duplicate rows, how does your table suppose to work with regards to its `primary key`?

Comment: Because they want to have the second value and can change its time_mode

Comment: If you want to insert the duplicate with one value changed, then simply write an insert statement with the same columns _except_ the column you want to change and in its place put the new value. e.g. `insert newtable (a, b, c, d, e) select top 1 a, b, c, 'newvalue', e from oldtable where <insert criteria>` ... or `insert newtable (a, b, c, d, e) select a, b, c, 'new value', e from newtable where <insert criteria>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally understood your problem correctly. Assuming you already have ran your first query that inserted the data without duplicates in your second table and now you want to insert the rest of the original duplicates.

In that case here's how you may do it, by eliminating the previous rows that you already have inserted:

```
WITH dupes AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY SwipeID, tdate, ttime, time_mode, raw_data,[Shift], eid, machineip
            ORDER BY (SELECT(0))
        ) AS row_num
    FROM SourceTable
)
INSERT INTO DestinationTable (/*columns*/)
SELECT /*values you need*/
FROM dupes
WHERE row_num > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just afraid that if they will run the query again, row counts 2 and above will be duplicated in the source table.

Comment: @Clarice Well, you could join on `SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM DestinationTable GROUP BY [relevant fields]` and do `WHERE row_num > total`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MYSQL;

```
INSERT INTO your_first_table(SwipeID,tdate,ttime,time_mode,raw_data,shift,eid,machineip)
    SELECT a.SwipeID,a.tdate,a.ttime,a.time_mode,a.raw_data,1,a.eid,a.machineip FROM your_second_table a ORDER BY a.SwipeID DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```